# Is it possible to cause a notebook to be hidden when pressing the close button?

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to cause a notebook to be hidden (`Visible -> False`) instead of closing it when pressing the close button in the title bar?

The `Messages` window seems to work this way.  The `Notebooks[]` function will list it even when it is not visible (or it has been "closed").  Is this special behaviour, or is it possible to make any notebook window behave like this?

---

Motivation:  As part of a user interface, I would like to gradually collect some information into a notebook (lets call it a "log-notebook").  The visibility of the log-notebook would be toggled with a button.  This log-notebook should persist across kernel sessions, but not across front end sessions (it will never be saved).

Comment: I don't know about changing the close button functionality, but you could turn the close button off by removing `"CloseBox"` from list of `WindowFrameElements` of the log notebook and add a docked cell with a button that sets `Visible->False` when pressed.

Comment: @Heike I was thinking the same while out to lunch, it might be the simplest way.

Answer (score 8):

Not a perfect solution, but it works for some extent. It definitely needs some further foolproofing though.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{}, WindowTitle -> "Log", 
   WindowFrameElements -> {}, NotebookEventActions -> {
     "WindowClose" :> DialogReturn[],
     "EscapeKeyDown" :> (
       SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Visible -> False];
       )}];

Button["Show", SetOptions[nb, Visible -> True]]
```

I used the hack Heike provided to remove the closebox from the window frame, since no matter how hard I tried to integrate the hiding functionality under `"WindowClose"` instead of `"ExcapeKeyDown"` without actually closing the window, it was always closed. Now the window is kept hidden if Esc is hit, and it is Alt+F4 that really terminates the window. If hidden, the provided `"Show"` button can be used to unhide the notebook.

Comment: +1: I didn't know about the `WindowFrameElements` option - that would have been useful!

Comment: @Simon: This was Heike's finding, not mine.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the Messages notebook might be a magic one. For example, 
If I run `Notebooks[]` in a new session, I see something like

```
{NotebookObject["Untitled-1"], NotebookObject["Messages"]}
```

I can then investigate the messages notebook by

```
NotebookGet[Notebooks[][[-1]]]
```

It looks basically normal, except

- it has no `WindowTitle` option, yet it has a title,
- it has the "Delete all Messages" docked cell, although it has no `DockedCells` option.

That is they are both in their default states and so don't show up in the returned `NotebookGet[]` expression.   (Although in the option inspector, a nonempty expression for `DockedCells` does show up, it does not have a checkmark next to it, so it is actually it's default state, which for normal notebooks should be `{}`. I'm not sure where it inherits this default from.)

And of course, the property that you noticed, 
"closing" the notebook merely sets the option
`Visible -> False`, and does not actually close the notebook.
Note that normal notebooks when made invisible do not show up in the Window menu. The message window always has an entry there.
I could not figure out how to replicate these properties.

---

However, here is a work around.

Store all of your log information in the global variable `$Log`, e.g.,

```
$Log = {1, 2, 3};
```

And define

```
CreateLog[vis:(True|False):False, title_String:"LogNotebook"] :=
  CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook[Dynamic[Column@$Log]],
  Visible -> vis, WindowTitle -> title, Saveable -> False, 
  NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> ($LogNotebook = CreateLog[])}]
```

Then you can create you log window using

```
$LogNotebook = CreateLog[True];
```

and everytime you close it, it is recreated, but in a hidden state. To show it again, you just need to run

```
SetOptions[$LogNotebook, Visible -> True]
```

To close it for real, just run

```
NotebookClose[$LogNotebook]
```

This can all be made to act and look nicer (but I've spent enough time on this already!)

Comment: Simon, you might be able to guess where this is going ;-) Stay tuned!

Comment: @Szabolcs: Now that you point it out, I can. Btw, I used your palette in a Mma.SE question for the first just a second ago - was really handy, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This creates a palette with a button to show the log notebook, creating it if it doesn't exists yet. The log notebook comes with a button in a docked cell which hides it when pressed.

```
CreatePalette[
  DynamicModule[{},
    Button["Show log",
      If[Head[$lognb] =!= NotebookObject,
        $lognb = CreateWindow[DockedCells -> 
          Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
           Button["Close", SetOptions[ButtonNotebook[], Visible -> False]]]], 
           "DockedCell"
          ],
          WindowFrameElements -> {}, WindowTitle -> "Log", 
          Saveable -> False, Visible -> True
        ],
        SetOptions[$lognb, Visible -> True]
      ];
      SetSelectedNotebook[$lognb]
    ]
  ],
  WindowTitle -> "Show Log"
]
```

To write data to the log notebook you could then do something like

```
NotebookWrite[$lognb, Cell["Some text", "Text"]]
```

Comment: This is very nice.  The remaining question is: how to detect that the notebook is already open if the kernel has quit in the meantime (I need to make this feel like a part of the Front End as much as possible, and definitely survive kernel restarts).  Do we need to get the notebook *name* (``NotebookTools`NotebookName``) or is there a better way?  Can we "tag" notebooks like cells?

Comment: @Szabolcs Using ``NotebookTools`NotebookName`` as an identification for the log should work as long as the user doesn't decide to reset the window title of the log notebook or set the title of another notebook to the title of the log notebook. Maybe as a more robust option you could save a dummy log notebook to disk and use `NotebookOpen` to make sure you select the right notebook.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, [`NotebookEventActions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookEventActions.html) allows you to specify an event handler for the `"WindowClose"` event, which will get triggered when a notebook window closes. But I haven't been able to figure out or find any way to *prevent* the close event from being sent to Mathematica's builtin handler. So as far as I know right now, it's not possible to actually prevent a notebook from closing.

What you can do (I think - I haven't tried) is register an event handler which will save the contents of the notebook when you close it.

```
nb = (* the notebook *)
SetOptions[nb, NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> NotebookSave[nb]}]
```

Alternatively you could have your event handler copy the contents of the notebook object into a new notebook, possibly an invisible one, before the existing notebook gets closed. Or do something else to preserve the notebook contents. It doesn't seem like a particularly satisfactory solution to me, though.

I can understand why WRI might have incentive not to allow a notebook to prevent itself from being closed: there's a security risk for a resource denial attack. In other words, if a Mathematica notebook is eating up too much CPU/RAM, you need to be able to shut the process down. (A real general-purpose GUI programming language will allow you to customize the behavior of the close button, though.)

Comment: if you do `LaunchKernels[4]`, then `ParallelDo[Sin[i], {i, 0, 10^6., .01}]` (say) and then close the notebook from which you executed this, the kernels don't stop running. So I am not sure closing notebooks is a security thing. Of course I could be missing lots of subtleties.

Answer (score 2):

As I also don't know a way how to avoid passing the window close event, here is another variant of the recreate notebook solution. It will survive kernel quits and probably could be combined with Rolfs `TaggingRule` [trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/891/169) to be more realiable than when just depending on the `WindowTitle`:

```
CreateDocument[{"some content"}, WindowTitle -> "Log", 
 Saveable -> False,
 NotebookEventActions -> {
   "WindowClose" :> (
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Visible -> False];
     NotebookPut[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]]
     )
   }]
```

When you need it, make it visible with something like this:

```
SetOptions[#, Visible -> True] & /@ 
 Select[Notebooks[], CurrentValue[#, WindowTitle] == "Log" &]
```