# How to Export the current graphic state of a dynamic module?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

After manipulating the graphics in a dynamic module like this:

[Synchronizing manual rotations for multiple Graphics3D outputs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21516/synchronizing-manual-rotations-for-multiple-graphics3d-outputs/21517#21517)

How do I get at the current graphic so that I can Export the image?

The answer might be burried in here [Using DynamicModule variables outside the DynamicModule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/886/using-dynamicmodule-variables-outside-the-dynamicmodule/891#891) someplace but i am unable to decipher it..

Comment: If don't need something automated, right click and copy graphic and then paste into `Export["filename.png",<paste here>]`

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work -- not a terribly satisfying approach though.

Comment: With a GraphcsRow/Grid you need to copy/paste the whole cell..

Comment: I agree - were I more imaginative, I would have posted an answer instead of a comment :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to identify the graphics object with a (local, dynamic) variable to use in a call to `Export[]`. It's easy to use a button to export from within the scope of the dynamic block. If you want the button to be external to the block, you can use `TaggingRules` as explained in your link. I prefer not to play around with extending the scope of variables.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
DynamicModule[{vp = {2, -2, 1}, vv = {0, 0, 1}, g},
 Grid[{{
    g = GraphicsRow[{Graphics3D[{Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}, 3]}, 
        SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
        ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]], 
       Graphics3D[{Cone[{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 4]}, 
        SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
        ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]], 
       Graphics3D[{Cone[{{1, 1, 1}, {9, 9, 9}}, 4]}, 
        SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
        ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]}]},  
   {Button["Save Figure", Export["dynamicfigure.png", g]]}}]]
```

[image: With a button!]

Comment: pretty slick!! 15 characters

Comment: You can also use an `InputField[]` with a dynamic string variable to define a file name, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Save Selection As...` (png for example) option in Menu. Using example of Corey Kelly:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A useful alternative based on Corey Kelly's answer, make the button "save" the dynamic varibles:

```
Button["save data", {savevp, savevv} = {vp, vv}; ]
```

Then outside the dynamic module these are available to make a 'statiic' graphic by repeating the graphic directive using ViewPoint -> savevp , etc.

Here I've "saved" a number of manipulated views, then combined into a single image for Export[].

[image]