# Is it possible for a Mathematica notebook to display its own metadata like last modified date and filename when opened?

Tags: date-and-time, files-and-directories, metadata

**Abstract:** when managing hundreds of notebook files without a git system (version management) it would be very convenient to automatically show its own filename and last modified date at the top when opened. Can this be done?

**About the Code:** Here is my very bad attempt at doing this that fails miserably.

```
FileDate["D:\Google Drive\projects\experiments\data\statistics.nb"]
```

Comment: If you have hundreds of files to keep track of, all under constant modification, then perhaps a version control system is a must. Consider the advice here: [What are the recommended settings for git when using with Mathematica projects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26174/27951).

Comment: This answer to [speedup and get more flexable control Notebook History](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100846/27951) might also be relevant, with some modification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one approach using a docked cell:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData[
    ToBoxes[Dynamic[
      Column[{NotebookFileName[], 
        DateString[
         Information[EvaluationNotebook[], "FileModificationTime"]]}],
       UpdateInterval -> 60]]]]]
```

[image]

The content updates once a minute.  You could set this globally by using `$FrontEnd` (survives through restarting the frontend) or `$FrontEndSession` (cleared by restarting the frontend), but you'll want to add some logic for what to display in a new notebook that has never been saved to disk (and maybe also notebooks that live in the cloud.)

Answer (score 0):

After digging through documentation I have found that there is a way and it's very easy. I packaged it into a nice little function for giving current user, current open file, and date modified and as a bonus I even included a function to clear memory.

Here ya go:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
systemInfo[] := Column[{Row[{Style["User: ", Bold], $Username}],
   Row[{Style["Filename: ", Bold], FileNameTake[NotebookFileName[]]}],
   Row[{Style["Last Modified: ", Bold], 
     DateString[FileDate[NotebookFileName[]]]}]}
  ]
clearMemory[] := {MemoryInUse[], Unprotect[In, Out], Clear[In, Out], 
   Protect[In, Out], MemoryInUse[]};
systemInfo[]
clearMemory[]
```