# How do I save the generated 2d random array for the next use?

Tags: random, save

I generated a 2d random array in $x-y$ plane with

```
L = 10;
random = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, L, L/10}, {y, 0, L, L/10}];
```

Now I want to save it for the next using by

```
iniF = Interpolation[Flatten[random, 1]];
inif[x_, y_] = c+iniF[x, y];
```

where $c$ is constant. How do you save the random data with a convenient format?
Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to save? Isn't the array already saved in `random`?

Comment: @ happy fish, Yes, it is in `random` of the memory. But after I close the notebook, or `ClearAll`, it is lost and I need to re-generate a random array. Here, I want to save `random` in a certain kind of `data` file in my disk for the next access. Thanks!

Comment: [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)

Comment: "_But after I close the notebook_, or ClearAll, it is lost and I need to re-generate a random array." No, closing the notebook won't clear the `random`, it's still there.

Comment: @xzczd true, but the OP may mean closing the kernel session. This may be useful (search for "persistent"): [Making large calculation results persistent](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97498/131)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general solution, you can always `Export` you data to a file.

```
L = 10;
random = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, L, L/10}, {y, 0, L, L/10}];

Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"rand.dat",Flatten[random,1]]
```

Next time you want to use this data

```
random = Import[NotebookDirectory[]<>"rand.dat"];
```

One benefit of using data file is you can use the data with any other language as well and also share with others. If you are working only with MMA, using a `Seed` as suggested by Wjx would be a better option.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to actually "save" it~

Answer (score 6):

Add this simple code before u run everything will let Random generate exactly the same result every time you run. If you're careful enough, you may find this in lot's of posts with randomly generated input.

```
SeedRandom["Whatever you write here, keep it the same in multiple runs!"]
```

Hope this can help you!