# Dynamic WindowSize cooperation with resize area

Tags: front-end, dynamic, notebooks, options

According to [**116030**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116030/5478):

> Front end options, which includes all box options, can take `Dynamic` heads. That basically means that the FE will compute the value of the Dynamic and use it for the option. And that it will be updated whenever a Dynamic dependency updates.

There is even a nice example with `Visible` [**1112**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1112/5478).

The problem is that for `WindowSize/Margins` options are overwritten with absolute values as soon as I use window frame elements (resize aread etc.) and move/resize the window.

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "size"}] = 
  1000 {1, 1/GoldenRatio};

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  WindowSize ->  Dynamic[
  CurrentValue[ EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "size"}]]
];

Dynamic @ InputForm @ CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]
```

> ```
> Dynamic[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "size"}]]
> ```

and after resizing:

> ```
> {1000, 619}
> ```

Can `WindowSize` and related options remain `Dynamic` during interaction with a notebook? Is this expected to happen?

It works for controllers:

```
DynamicModule[{x = {100, 100}},
 Pane[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> Dynamic[x],
  AppearanceElements -> All
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I don't see any way to interact with the front-end at the level you seem to need. What are you trying to accomplish? If I knew that, perhaps I could suggest a work-around.

Comment: @m_goldberg I wanted to put there something like `Dynamic[temp, Initialization :> (temp = init)]`, where both are pointing to some TaggingRules. The point would be to have "non-saveable options" so that e.g. WindowSize will always reset to `init` value when nb is reopened. I could do that with `NotebookDynamicExpression` but it is unique and I would rather avoid that.

Comment: So you want a notebook that doesn't remember its size between sessions, but always opens at fixed size that you have set?

Comment: @m_goldberg yes, but that is another question I will probably ask later.