# Creating notebooks with specific options being editable but not saveable

Tags: notebooks, options, customization

#### The goal

To create a notebook whose options, when the notebook is opened, are fixed regardless of edits done to the notebook.

E.g. `WindowSize -> Automatic` and `WindowMargins -> 30` should be a starting value even if one has saved that notebook from full screen mode.

#### The motivation

Notebooks are shared, e.g. through Google Drive, and opened on different devices. It is annoying to open a notebook, which was previously used with 250% magnification, taking half of 4K screen, on a 13" laptop.

#### The question

Is there a good approach which is flexible, doesn't trigger dynamic warning and if possible works from a stylesheet?

I've thought that maybe something like `WindowSize -> Dynamic[dynamic, Initialization :> (dynamic = init)]` where `dynamic` and `init` are references to specific `TaggingRules`.

It won't work [because notebook options are overwritten](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125589/5478). Moreover, `Initialization` can be triggered when the Kernel is restarted which is not desirable.

#### Edit:

I have not received any answers so I'm moving tests I've done to an answer. I think they fit there and the goal is to reduce unanswered stack. But I will gladly accept any answer that fulfills all stated requirements.

Comment: Like the notebooks in Documentation Center?

Comment: @Silvia they are not saveable at all. I want to use them normally.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your purpose... The `FileChangeProtection` option (for `Notebook`) looks interesting, might lead to a solution for your question.

Comment: @Silvia no worries. I can't find any info about that option :)

Comment: I saw it in Doc notebooks. They use it as `FileChangeProtection -> None`, I'm guessing maybe it also accepts a function value.

Answer (score 3):

#### Approaches (none is perfect):

1. `NotebookDynamicExpression`, something along those lines:

   ```
   NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> Automatic], 
     None
   ]
   ```

   **I don't like it**. The reasons are:

   - `NotebookDynamicExpression` is unique and there are no tools to automatically merge/compose multiple events assigned at different times.
   - It won't fire when the Kernel is restarted but only because there is a bug. So at the end it will have the same flaw. (*although experience tells me I don't have to worry about that in a near future*)

     [If NotebookDynamicExpression doesn't fire in new kernel sessions, it certainly should.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-the-most-common-usual-ways-to-make-palettes-with-non-trivial-function/109638#comment3498_1113)

At the end the method is poor because it triggers `Enable Dynamic Updating` warning in the notebook (on an untrusted path) while nothing serious is going on.

2. `NotebookEventActions`

   ```
   NotebookEventActions :> {"WindowClose" :> (
     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> Automatic, WindowMargins -> 30];
     NotebookSave[]
     ),
     PassEventsDown -> True
   }
   ```

   Is not general enough as it misses things like `NotebookClose[]`. It also flashes before it is closed but this is not so important.

Comment: The `"WindowClose"` approach could instead be done on `{"MenuCommand", "Save"}`? That way any time it is *saved* that will fire (although I suppose this might be super annoying...). It might be a bit more robust.

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes, I do not want to readjust the window after each save :)

Comment: One other option is to add a context-menu item that would do this. That way people could just right-click and apply via the menu. It still requires a bit of work on their part, but is totally applicable via stylesheet, isn't dynamic, and is robust.

Comment: @b3m2a1 sounds useful. My use case involves people that can be bothered with such stuff :) that is why I aim in a more automatc solution here.